# having problem with html5 validation for IE specific when using setCustomValidity()

Tags: javascript, html, validation, internet-explorer

I have login form with check box privacy policy(required), and want to display custom html5 validation message if not checked and form submit click. I have used the inline javascript:

```
<input name="privacypolicy" title="Please agree to our privacy policy" id="privacypolicy" required="" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please agree to our privacy policy')" type="checkbox" value="agree">
```

This works for chrome and firefox. But does not work properly for IE(11 or edge).
Scenario:
1. if everything is correct and submitted it works.
2. if this is not checked and then submitted, it shows the popup validation message. But even after checked and submit, it still show the error message and forms does not submits at all.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the following code, it works well on my side (using IE11 and Chrome)

Javascript script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function page_load() {
        document.getElementById("privacypolicy").setCustomValidity("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions!");
    };
</script>
```

Html code:

```
<body onload="page_load();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <p>
                <input title="Please agree to our privacy policy" required="required"
                    onchange="this.setCustomValidity(validity.valueMissing ? 'Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions!!!!' : '');"
                    id="privacypolicy" type="checkbox" name="privacypolicy" />
                I accept the <u>Terms and Conditions</u>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The screenshot as below:
[image]

Comment: very Good hack as IE does not support https://caniuse.com/#search=setCustomValidity

Comment: Question on this one. How to remove required of a field that has customvalidity. I am getting this error `profile:1 An invalid form control with name='end_month' is not focusable.` because the field is hidden when user ticks a checkbox.

Comment: @RyanAquino, If I understand accurately, your field in question is hidden or became hidden as a result of some programming condition. I would say, best way would be to ensure $('#that_field_id').attr('required", false); while you try to hide that field. That will exempt this field from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement your own event listener?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var invalid = function(e) {   
    if(e.target.validity.valueMissing){
      e.target.setCustomValidity("Please agree to our privacy policy");
      return;
    }
  };

  var privacypolicy = document.getElementsByName("privacypolicy");
  privacypolicy[0].oninvalid = invalid;
  privacypolicy[0].oninput = function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
  };
});
```

and the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Privacy Policy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="">
      <label for="privacypolicy"> Privacy Policy </label>
      <input name="privacypolicy" id="privacypolicy" required="" type="checkbox" value="agree">
      <br/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I can't test this code into IE11 because I'm using ubuntu but in chrome works great!